# MySQL LEFT JOIN and IS NULL

Tags: mysql, left-join, isnull

i have a query that goes like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.id_a = table_b.id_a
WHERE
table_b.field = 'something' OR table_b.field IS NULL
```

i want to have the records with table_b.field = 'something' or the ones where theres is no record in table_b for the row in table_a.
when i add the IS NULL the query takes about 60 seconds to execute vs 0.4 seconds without it.

anyone can explain this behavior?
i think the IS NULL denies some optimization, but im not completely sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have an index on Field in Table_b? If it is in a concatenated index, make sure it is the first one.

Comment: Actually your left join ensures you get the data when it is null. You need to just move the table_b.field = 'something' into the join.

Comment: Actually your left join ensures you get the data when it is null. You need to just move the table_b.field = 'something' into the join.

SELECT * 
FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.id_a = table_b.id_a and table_b.field = 'something'

Comment: well, yes, with an index it regains the speed, but i still dont understand why this happens

Comment: @Jarry Indexes are a means to access the data faster. Suppose you are searching for a definition in a 1000-page book, wouldn't it help if there was an index of all the key words at the end of the book, so that we first look up the word, read the page number and go to that page directly? The alternative is to keep reading the book from the start to the end and note down all pages where that word occured, which will be a longer process.

Comment: thank for the response.
i know what an index does, what i dont know its why the lack of an index doesn matters without the is null clause. 
anyway, thanks for the explanation